# Index 124411787 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 21659

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I am training a model using a dataset. I am getting index out of bounds error for my data while computing similar_indices. my dataframe has 2 fields storyid and title. storyid is a long numerical value and title is text
code with issues:

```
for idx, row in ds.iterrows():
            similar_indices = cosine_similarities[idx].argsort()[:-100:-1]
            similar_items = [(cosine_similarities[idx][i], ds['id'][i])
                             for i in similar_indices]
```

Error log :

```
similar_indices = cosine_similarities[idx].argsort()[:-100:-1]
IndexError: index 124411787 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 21659
```

Comment: try `print(cosine_similarities.shape)` and `print(idx)`. You'll notice that `idx` is larger than the number of rows in `cosine_similarities`

Comment: printing `print(cosine_similarities.shape)` gives `(21675, 21675)`   . I cannot print `idx` as th loop never gets executed. Now the error is : `IndexError: index 124411795 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 21675`

Comment: Add a print statement as the first line inside the loop or debug using ipdb.

Comment: I did as you said. I made changes, and output is : `print(cosine_similarities.shape) : (22163, 22163)`        and                   `print(idx) : 124418777`   .                                    Error message is :  `IndexError: index 124418777 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 22163`

Comment: So that's it. It says that you're trying to access the 124411795th row in `cosine_similarities` whereas it only has 21675 rows.